# Use getfinmdat() in the cbw package to extract stock data and return HTTP error 403

Tags: r, quantmod

I want to extract stock data using `getfinmdat()` in `cbw` package:

```
library(cbw)
df <- getfinmdat(symbols = c("MSFT", "AAPL", "^gspc"),
                   symnames = c("msft", "aapl", "sp500"),
                   from = "2001-01-01",
                   to = "2021-03-31")
print(df)
```

But it returns an `Error message: HTTP error 403`. Does anyone know what's going on? Is it because Yahoo Finance stopped providing stock data service interface?

```
Error in getSymbols.yahoo(Symbols = "MSFT", env = <environment>, verbose = FALSE, : Unable to import “MSFT”. MSFT download failed after two attempts. Error message: HTTP error 403.
```

Comment: Is this a cran package?

Comment: Nope, I don't think so, https://apps.olin.wustl.edu/faculty/chib/rpackages/cbw/